# Scaling up big data in Jupyter and SciKit-Learn Random Forrest

Tags: python, linux, scikit-learn, google-compute-engine, jupyter-notebook

Running big data in Jupyter Notebooks with Sci-Kit Learn

I usually try to segment my issues into specific component questions, so bear with me here! We are attempting to model some fairly sparse health conditions against pretty ordinary demographics. We have access to a lot of data, hundreds of millions of records, we would like to get up to 20 million records into a Random Forest Classifier. I have been told that sci-kit learn should be able to handle this. We are running into issues. The sort that don't generate tracebacks! Just dead processes.

I recognize that this is not much to go on,, but what I’m looking for is any advice on how to scale and or debug this process of scaling this up.

So we want to run truly pretty big data though Jupyter notebooks and Scikit Learn, primarily Random Forest.

On a 8gb core i7 Notebook running Linux 14.04 and Jupyter running Py 3.5 and the notebook running Python 2.7 code via conda env. (fwiw we store the data in Google Big Query, we use the Pandas Big Query connector for this which allows us to run the same code both on the local machines and in the cloud)

I can get a 100,000 record dataset consumed and model built with a bunch of diagnostic reports and charts that we have built into the notebook, no problem. The following scenarios all use the same code and the same versions of the respective Conda environments but several different pieces of hardware in an attempt to scale up our process.

When I expand the dataset to 1,000,000 records, I get about 95% of the way into the data load from Big query and I see a lot of pegged cpu activity and I guess what seems to be memory swap activity (viewing it on the Linux process monitor) the entire machine seems to freeze Load progress from Big Query seems to stop for an extended period of time, and the browser indicates that it has lost connection to the kernel, sometimes with the browser message indicating failed status and sometimes with the broken link icon on the Jupyter NB, amazingly, it eventually completes normally. And the output in fact gets completely rendered in the notebook.

I tried to put some memory profiling code in using psutil, and interestingly I saw no changes as the Dataframe went through several processes, including a fairly substantial “get_dummies” process which expands the categorical variables into separate columns (which would presumably expand memory usage) but when doing this after an extended time the memory usage stats printed out but the model diagnostics never rendered in the browser (as they had previously) the terminal window indicated a web socket timeout and the browser froze. I finally terminated the notebook terminal.

Interesting my colleague can process 3,000,000 records successfully on his 16gb Macbook.

When we try to process 4,000,000 records on a 30 gb VM on Google Compute engine we get an error indicating “Mem error”. So even a huge machine does not allow us to complete.

I realize we could use serially built models and or spark, but we wish to use sci kit learn and Random Forrest and get through the memory issue if possible?

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you're looking for but if your strike-rate in the dataset is very low, I would try undersampling the negatives until the dataset is within a managable size.

Comment: yes that gets part of it done but really want to understand/debug the issues outlined..

Comment: is the input matrix to your model sparse ? (i.e. are you calling `get_dummies` with `sparse=True` or doing anything else that might make your values a dense numpy array ?)

Comment: no, I'm using the pandas get dummies, does not generate sparse..

Comment: so you should definately be converting your `DataFrame.values` to a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` matrix before you're sending it to the classifier, you can  also call `pd.get_dummies(df, sparse=True)` to decrease the memory footprint of that step

Comment: Interesting and will give it a try, still does not answer the base question of scaling up to use big machines, I need some idea of how to debug the process?

Comment: Well another thing to try is set `n_jobs=-1` when you initialise the `RandomForestClassifier`, this will use all the available cores to train the trees, this will speed things up if you're on a multi-core machine. also set `verbose=1` in the `RandomForestClassifier` and you should get some more debug messages